# Manipulate the value in php

Tags: php, input, submit, smarty

I've been searching around the web but I've found nothing about my problem and I really don't know how to solve it.

I have this:

```
{foreach from=$projects item="currProject"}
   {foreach from=$currProject key="k" item="p"}
      {if $k === 'id'}
           Project {$p}:
      {elseif $k === 'name'}
           {$p} <br>
      {elseif $k === 'url'}
           <form action="/Homepage/index.php" method="get">
              <pre><input type="submit" name="rt" value="Go"><br><br>
           </form>
      {/if}
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Well want I want to do, is that instead of sending the value of "Go" sends another value, but still showing "Go" as the name. For example:

I have another .php file where I have a $_GET magic variable, which it will do the "routing". So, with this code, no matter what, it will always send "Go", what it will always send me to the same route, even if I want to do the routing elsewhere. What do you recommend me to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not include a hidden input in the form?

Comment: And the other input points somehow to the hidden one or what do you exactly mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{foreach from=$projects item="currProject"}
   {foreach from=$currProject key="k" item="p"}
      {if $k === 'id'}
           Project {$p}:
      {elseif $k === 'name'}
           {$p} <br>
      {elseif $k === 'url'}
           <form action="/Homepage/index.php" method="get">
              <input type="hidden" name="{whatever}" value="realValue" />
              <pre><input type="submit" name="rt" value="Go"><br><br>
           </form>
      {/if}
   {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Then, when routing:

```
$_GET['{whatever}'];
```

Assuming `rt` is for routing, just name the hidden input `rt`.

Comment: Yes, if you're looking at `rt` for the routing value.